# Rails changing variable name in for loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 5 fields in my Rails app in my `Student`'s table such as `food_desc_one`, `food_desc_two`, etc. all the way up to five. I am writing a method in my Student controller which loops over to check the values that are null. I thought the best way to do it would be with a for loop, so I did the following:

```
for i in 0..5
  if student.food_desc_"#{in_words(i)}" != ''
    . . .
  end
end
```

where `in_words` is a helper method I have defined earlier. However, I get the error `undefined method 'food_desc_' for #<Student:0x0000000b2e75d8>` which I assume is because of me trying to append the number at the end of the variable .. is there another way to accomplish this? Or will I have to check each field seperately? All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
student.send("food_desc_#{in_words(i)}")
```